# MySQL Replace with a " in the statement

Tags: php, mysql, phpbb

I have a PHPBB forum and at the moment quotes in the forum look like this:

> [quote="USERNAME"]
>   MESSAGE
>   [/QUOTE"]

However I need to remove the " from the `[/QUOTE"]`.

I have tried replace statements like this:

```
UPDATE phpbb_posts
SET post_text = REPLACE (post_text, '[/QUOTE"]', '[/QUOTE]');
```

But no luck. I've also tried double quotes etc. but I still can't quite get it.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Based on your attempt, I'm assuming you already have the data in the database and need to modify it? or is this applied to new incoming data where you can use PHP to change the data before inserting it?

Comment: I can't reproduce this - appears to be working as is.

Comment: Note, whichever approach you take to fix this, either in the database or with php code, the problem will continue to occur with each new quote.   You will need to modify the actual php code to prevent it from reoccurring;  it is likely a simple fix.

Comment: Thanks for the replies so far. It won't be an issue going forward, it's migrated data from another forum I'm trying to change so that it works properly with PHPBB. The data is already in the database and I'm just trying to change it. Thanks

Comment: @Dan, please make sure there is no white space character in `[/QUOTE"]`. If the string contains a tab space etc, some editors will not display is. Or if `"` is a Word special character instead of standard `"`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using str_replace in your PHP code and then use this for your update query, assuming you have your content in a variable called `$post_text`

```
str_replace('[/QUOTE"]', '[/QUOTE]',$post_text  )
```

Here's the [documentation on `str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: That's a bad assumption to make - The attempt shown in the question should affect all records in the table that already exist - not exclusively new records being inserted.

Comment: This is not an update.  This is a variable within his php code.   when he does the update, he would be assigning all of the above into a new variable, wherein he would update the row specifically as stated.   If he wants to update existing records, he could pull those from the table, make the update and correct them.  There are multiple ways of handling this;  I'm suggesting one.  If you have another one, please provide a different answer.

Comment: The asker hasn't mentioned _anything_ about PHP apart from the tag. Querying for the data, then modifying and re-inserting it would change id values. Issuing a `UPDATE` is _explicitly_ described in his attempt. I would post a different answer, but the query posted in the question appears to work just fine.

Comment: again,  I'm only suggesting that if you have a different solution, I recommend providing it.   The point of this site is to provide information.  It would help not only the OP but others who seek answers while searching.

Comment: Note, either way, whether you update the db or edit the existing strings, the problem will continue to reoccur each time a user enters a new quote;  that will need to be fixed in the php code.